# Android spinner display char array. Error: type argument cannot be of primitive type

Tags: android

I am trying to display an array of character in a spinner.

```
private char[] locations = new char[]{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',};
```

here I am trying to add them

```
// add items into spinner dynamically
public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

    ArrayAdapter<char> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<char>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, locations);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerPosition.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Error: type argument cannot be of primitive type

anyone suggest another way of doing this.

Comment: why not use `String`?

Comment: Could do alright, can it not be done with CHAR?

Comment: another hint: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: WHY vote this down???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, don't use a primitive type. Use String instead. Put all your characters in quotation marks (`"a", "b", "c"`)... and replace char with String everywhere.

As the error says, it simply can not be a primitive type.